# Using enum and ValueNotifier for DropdownMenu in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

Hi what my goal is to display enum values inside of a dropdown menu and to replace setState with ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder. I'm fairly new to flutter and currently I only know how to display dropdown menu when we have a list of strings and its using setState but how can I modify it. So for instance we have enum Locations={belgium,germany,spain, etc}

This is my code so far:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('hi'),
      ),
      drawer: FoodNotifyDrawer('name'),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              DropdownButton(
                // Not necessary for Option 1
                value: _selectedLocation,
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedLocation = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: _locations.map((location) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(location),
                    value: location,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              Text('Option 2'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum Locations { belgium, germany, spain }

class DropDownTest extends StatelessWidget {
DropDownTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
final ValueNotifier<Locations> _selectedValue =
  ValueNotifier<Locations>(Locations.belgium);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: ValueListenableBuilder<Locations>(
        valueListenable: _selectedValue,
        builder: (context, v, _) {
          return DropdownButton<Locations>(
            value: v,
            onChanged: (Locations? newValue) {
              if (newValue != null) {
                _selectedValue.value = newValue;
              }
            },
            items: Locations.values.map((d) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text(d.name),
                value: d,
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can; you can use the same enum values as the values of your dropdown, as in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/22ddbddfa59a802ebae34f3e552d65c3) I created for you, which pretty much uses all enum values and processes them as such:

```
enum Locations { belgium, germany, spain }
```

and shows them in the dropdown as such:

```dart
DropdownButton(
                // Not necessary for Option 1
                value: _selectedLocation,
                onChanged: (Locations? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedLocation = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: Locations.values.map((location) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(toBeginningOfSentenceCase(location.name).toString()),
                    value: location,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              )
```

Run the Gist above through DartPad.dev and you should get the following output:

[image]

The rest should be straight forward using **ValueNotifier** and **setState**.